# Sensitivity List in Verilog

Tags: verilog

for example, if there is a case when an output "clear" is sensitive for both the negedge and posedge, do we write it as: always @ (negedge clear, posedge clear)?

Or is it impossible to have both sensitivities occurring at the same time?

Comment: I'm not sure if your example is valid Verilog, but you might just as well write `@clear`.

Comment: For dual data rate, SystemVerilog supports `always_ff @(edge clear)`. You will need to check with your tool set that `edge` is supported

Answer (score 2):

That would be valid Verilog. However as The Photon suggested, it will be the same as @clear. If you want a dual-edge flip-flop, you will need a vendor-specific model.